# Terrible performance of MapControl with multiple children in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, maps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `MapControl` which is supposed to be filled with multiple objects (500+). These objects represent some kind of POI. When the user taps on the object (pushpin) I display more info about the POI. So, I need:

1. A `MapControl` capable of handling high amount of child objects
2. Intercept `Tapped`event of the child object

In order to achieve the second goal I decided to define my own pushpin template:

```
  <maps:MapControl x:Name="Map">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
      <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Image Width="40"
                 Height="40"
                 Source="{ ... }"
                 Tapped="OnPushpinTappedAsync"
                 maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
                 maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding AnchorPoint}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
  </maps:MapControl>
```

This works great except for the fact that.. the visual out of such approach is AWFULL. Every time I move a map, every `Pushpin` flickers a lot. It's like they are not, I don't know, bound to the position. They are also lagging. It looks really bad. Rendering of those objects is really poor.

The alternative is to add elements to the `MapControl`'s `MapElements` property. It makes rendering of those objects really nice. 
But then I loose `binding` ability and will have to workaround it - I'm not a big fan of that. There's also a second problem - from what I've read, rendering objects of the `MapElements` collection is a best effort deal. So it does not guarantee that it will succeed. And that is not an option for me, as in the future I plan to add clustering functionality, so I need to have a full control over what is being rendered on the map and what is not.

Do you have any idea why these `MapControl`'s elements flickers so much? What can I do to prevent it? Thanks in advance for any hint or answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the Image control?

Comment: I have just tried it, and there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same problem. Seems to me, that the MapControl is completely broken. There are many more bugs besides performance :(

You cannot really solve the problem, but you can create a "oldschool" WP8.0 Silverlight application and use something like this:

```
        <Page xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps">
            <map:Map Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myMap">
                <tool:MapExtensions.Children>
                    <tool:MapItemsControl>
                       ... and so on ...
```

This performs great but of course you have to change everything from Win(P)RT to Silverlight...

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem, but I find this [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XAML.MapControl) to be usefull.

Hopefully Microsoft updates the MapControl for Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Tag="{Binding index_of_collection}"
```

and this:

```
OnPushpinTappedAsync()

int index = (int)(sender as Image).Tag;  //index_of_collection
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer helps?